# Magento 2.1 set default filter in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layered-navigation, category-products, category-listing

I need to apply the default filter in all category pages. could you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer this site.: https://www.magentech.com/blog/item/829-quick-guide-to-configure-layered-navigation-in-magento-2

Comment: I suggest to you, if you are using theme navigation than disabled navigation module.

Comment: I am using default theme i.e., luma

Comment: @here I want to apply one custom attribute selected by default as like when category will be selected by default right so like that I need to select.